# Search if user is part of specific group

Tags: 2011, core-service, authorization

We have implemented a functionality via the Core Service and we want to have this functionality only available to one SDL Tridion group (e.g. TridionGrp) and all others should get an unauthorized error.

We are able to check for the users who are directly part of this TridionGrp however how can we check if a user part of another group (e.g. TridAccess) while that other group is part of TridionGrp.

So how can we recursively check the user membership in order to validate the access?

Comment: Which API are you using? Is this TOM.Net (for example from a template or event system module) or the Core Service?

Comment: Core Service API

Answer (score 5):

## Update

If Peter is correct, my answer makes no sense of course! I will leave it for now until Hiren has confirmed that the group memberships are indeed expanded automatically.

## Original answer

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to go through the group memberships recursively. For example (untested code!!)

```
TrusteeData trustee = (TrusteeData) client.Read(TrusteeID, new ReadOptions());
List<GroupMembershipData> groupMemberships = GetGroupMemberships (trustee);

private List<GroupMembershipData> GetGroupMemberships (TrusteeData trustee) 
{
    List<GroupMembershipData> memberships = new List<GroupMembershipData>();
    foreach (GroupMembershipData groupMshpData in trustee.GroupMemberships)
    {
        memberships.Add(groupMshpData.Group);
        subMemberships = GetGroupMemberships(groupMshpData.Group);
        if (subMemberships.Count > 0)
            memberships.AddRange(subMemberships);
    }
    return memberships;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Group memberships are automatically expanded for the current user.

So just call `GetCurrentUser()` and check if the relevant group is in the `GroupMemberships` array.

Comment: will GroupMemberships array contains both Tridion group as well as active directory groups?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's only Tridion Groups, but isn't that what Group Sync is for?

Comment: Can you please provide details on Group Sync?

Comment: [Documentation link](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_A48A93FE5F8C4ACCA3C034A651C914DE). Basically, users will be added to the Content Manager (with the relevant groups) based on the information in your directory service.

Comment: We are using coreservice to get membership data and as suggested by you, we tried UserData currentUser1 = (UserData)_client.Read(<user id>, new ReadOptions()); however the groupmembership attribute for currentUser1 is showing as count 0. Can you please suggest what am I missing?

Comment: You have to use GetCurrentUser, not Read.

Comment: thanks GetCurrentUser was the trick. However, there is still one problem: The scenario that we have is: user is part of active directory group (For e.g. AD IT Dev) which in turn is part of Tridion Group (For e.g. IT Dev). We want to check if user is part of IT Dev group and however groupmembership  gives only "Everyone" group as user is part of AD group "AD IT Dev". Is there any way to check the Active directory groups also with Tridion groups.

Comment: GetCurrentUser shows every Tridion group for me (including the nested ones that I'm implicitly a part of). I'm not sure I follow your explanation of your groups, but I'm pretty sure that AD groups are not exposed - only Tridion groups. If you open the user in Tridion, which groups does it show he is a member of? And are those groups part of this IT Dev group somewhere along the chain?

Comment: Started a new thread: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-the-members-of-a-tridion-group-which-is-mapped-to-an-a